# How would you do this with regular expression javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm in the process of learning javascript and get confused by regular expressions (regex). It can sometimes be the syntax but mostly my understanding of regex is very poor. for instance `var pattern = /^0+$/;` just looks like crap to me.

Can this jQuery if/else statement be converted to a regex method? and if so, how/why?

```
// Set header link widths based on how many there are

var nav = $('#nav_header a');
var navlinks = $('#nav_header').children('a').length;
if (navlinks == 1) {
    nav.css('width', '100%');
} else if (navlinks == 2) {
    nav.css('width', '50%');
} else if (navlinks == 3) {
    nav.css('width', '32%');
} else if (navlinks == 4) {
    nav.css('width', '25%');
} else if (navlinks == 5) {
    nav.css('width', '20%');
} else if (navlinks == 6) {
    nav.css('width', '16.6%');
} else if (navlinks == 7) {
    nav.css('width', '14.25%');
} else if (navlinks == 8) {
    nav.css('width', '12%');
} else if (navlinks == 9) {
    nav.css('width', '11%');
} else if (navlinks == 10) {
    nav.css('width', '10%');
} else {
    nav.css('width', '8%');
}
```

Are there specific techniques to writing regex JS, things to consider and to try and keep it human-readable?

Thanks for your help and advice :)

Comment: Whats the pattern? 1 = 100%, 2 = 50%, 3 = 32%, 4 = 25% ?

Comment: What does this have to do with regex?  You aren't matching anything.

Comment: @tymeJV yeah just dividing 100 by the number of children, as a percentage

Comment: Regular Expressions are not the answer to **all** programming problems *(the same goes for jQuery btw)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My advice, create a simple look-up array:

```
var percents = ["100%", "50%", "32%", "25%", "20%", "16.6%", "14.25%", "12%", "11%", "10%", "8%"];

var nav = $('#nav_header a');
var navlinks = $('#nav_header').children('a').length;
navlinks == 0 ? nav.css("width", "8%") : nav.css("width", percents[navlinks - 1]);
```

Comment: Your code doesn't include the `else` statement where `navlinks` is `0`

Comment: @Patryk -- It does now :)

Answer (score 2):

> var pattern = /^0+$/; just looks like crap to me.

Actually that is an easy one, it only matches a string if that string contains only `0`s.

> Can this jQuery if/else statement be converted to a regex method? and if so, how/why?

No it can't. Regular expressions are used to find patterns in text or split the text around a given pattern or replace a given pattern. They can't be used instead of conditional statements.

Comment: Thanks @Sniffer. Really helpful. Is there a specific way to go about reading regular expressions? Maybe formatting? Or is it just a case of learning and using?

Comment: @M_Willett It is a case of learning and using, practicing is essential. You can start learning at [Regular Expressions Info](http://www.regular-expressions.info).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex for that :)

```
var nav = $('#nav_header a');
var navlinks = $('#nav_header').children('a').length;
var widths = ['100%', '50%', '32%', '25%', '20%', '16.6%', '14.25%', '12%', '11%', '10%']
nav.css('width', (navlinks >= 1 && navlinks <= 10) ? widths[navlinks-1] : '8%')
```